# -Djava.ext.dirs=[...]/Sdk/tools/lib:[...]/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64 is not supported when starting monkeyrunner on linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, monkeyrunner

I want to run `monkeyrunner` but if I run `mypath/Sdk/tools/bin/monkeyrunner` I get:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=mypath/Sdk/tools/lib:/mypath/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64 is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I found some questions like this but for MacOS and Windows but none for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Other questions suggest to install java 8. For me `java -version` showed that I was using corretto 11, so I installed corretto 8 as well (via .deb).

With `find . -name '*corretto*' 2>/dev/null` I found the executables as `./usr/lib/jvm/java-*-amazon-corretto/jre/bin/java`. After setting

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/jre'
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

`java -version` shows corretto 11 and monkeyrunner can start up.

To fix the script I add those two lines before the call to java in the last line:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/jre'
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
exec java -Xmx128M $os_opts $java_debug -Djava.ext.dirs="$frameworkdir:$swtpath" -Djava.library.path="$libdir" -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir="$progdir" -jar "$jarpath" "$@"
```